# OpenId-Connect (OIDC) with Spring Security but without sticky sessions or central storage

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, openid-connect

We want to configure our service with OIDC authentication against a keycloak server.

We are using spring security 5.2.0 with spring boot 2.2.0.

There are multiple instances of our service and we do not want to share any state between them with central storage (e.g. databases, distributed caches, ...), nor use sticky sessions. That's why we already implemented two custom cookie-based repositories for authorization info that would normally reside in the server-side session. (`CookieBasedRequestCache` and `CookieBasedAuthorizationRequestRepository`). That way the oidc redirect flow works except for the last step where the user is redirected to the original url:

After successul login, keycloak redirects back to our instance with a code. This instance (let's call it 'A') validates the `OAuth2AuthorizationResponse` against the initial keycloak authorization request. It gets the information from a cookie we saved earlier in the login process to avoid Spring Security's session management.

Now, if the authorization response is successfully validated, instance 'A' sends a final redirect to the original URL that the user requested before logging in. If this request is answered by the same instance 'A', everything works fine. But if a different instance (say 'B') answers the request, it doesn't work because B doesn't know anything about the user's authentication state.

Questions:

1. Is there a cookie-based JWT repository we could use to save the access token across instances? Or how would one implement it?
2. Where in spring security's code (filter chain?) is the check whether the user is authenticated? This would be helpful for answering the final redirect to the original url.

Comment: Did you get any insights on this?

Comment: Hi @Dirk, not really. As JWTs are not intended to be passed to the user via a cookie, we would indeed have to use sticky sessions or some kind of session storage like Redis which works across all instances of a service